# How do you see Jupyter notebook on a microsoft/cntk docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, cntk

I just installed the microsoft/cntk docker image and I was wondering how can I see the Jupyter notebook interface (in order to do the tutorials included in the docker image at /cntk/Tutorials) ?

For another docker image I simply did the following command:

docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /home/name/notebooks:/home/ds/notebooks dataquestio/python3-starter

and then I opened my browser and went to localhost:8888

Thank you

Comment: I solved it, it was the same command: docker run -it -p 8888:8888 microsoft/cntk, but what I was doing wrong was forgetting to add the parameter --ip 0.0.0.0 to the command jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising this.

We have updated the Wiki on how to run Jupyter Notebooks in Docker containers.

See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTk/wiki/CNTK-Docker-Containers#using-docker-container-to-run-cntk-jupyter-notebook-tutorials